# Magento 2.3 it's not working properly in localhost

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8

I have installed **Magento 2.3** in my localhost and it's a successfully installed. But When I open an admin URL it comes with blank URL. Also, my homepage comes without Magento default logo. And i am facing another issue on homepage When I clicked on to create an account it redirects successfully but it comes with a blank page.

[image]

Please see attached images for better ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this small hack will help you. i remebered i had an same issue some time back so may be this one will help you. You have to change some code in `Validator.php`. In the Validator.php there is one method(**isPathInDirectories**) so you have to change the below line

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

to

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Path : `...vendor\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php`

Comment: This resolved the problem, thanks. Now admin panel is properly worked but Homepage in not worked the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

@Dhruv after using the command `indexing:reindex` the Homepage works perfectly.

```sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Admin>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd xampp\php

C:\xampp\php>php C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento3\bin\magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:09
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05

C:\xampp\php>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue while installing Magento 2.3.3 in my localhost - XAMPP Server. It's successfully installed, but when I opening the admin panel, it appeared a blank screen like the below image.
 [Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj0rB.jpg)

The Solution is:

After that, I changed the code like below.

Go to this Path: **..\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File** then Open this file **Validator.php**

Then Search this line **$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);**

Replace to **$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));**

[Image for reference to change the Validator.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5xtn.jpg)

Now Admin Panel will appear successfully.

Admin Panel appeared, but the issue is *Magento logo does not appear on the login screen*. After logging the admin [Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbwE7.jpg), Icons don't appear on the dashboard also its continuously loading like the below images [Icon Don't Appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnaDk.jpg)

The solution is:

Go to this Path: ..\app\etc then Open this file di.xml

Then search this line
 **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink**

To Replace the line 
 **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy**

[Check this image for replacing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FyxL.jpg) & [Make sure the code should come like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUEwP.jpg)

Now Go to the Admin Panel and Refresh the page. It's Successfully working without issues. All icons have appeared also Logo is appeared.

[Admin Panel Sucess image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SvVk.jpg)

Now Go to Client Area, if you update sample content, the page looks like this image [Client Page with Sample Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf0eb.jpg). Otherwise, it will appear like "CMS homepage content goes here".

Everything is working good.

I hope it will use to solve this issue.